# How to set locale in the current terminal's session?

Tags: bash, encoding, terminal, locale, rxvt

I'm trying to change encoding in the urxvt current session by changing `LANG` variable. Howerever, it seems like it doesn't apply immediately. Here is what I do:

Available locales:

```
$ locale -a
C
en_US.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.koi8r
ru_RU.utf8
```

Before setting new locale:

```
$ echo "а" | od -t x1
0000000 d0 b0 0a # good! UTF-8
#       | a ||NL|
```

After:

```
$ export LANG=ru_RU.KOI8-R
$ echo "а" | od -t x1
0000000 d0 b0 0a # hm..expect 'c1 0a'
```

Fork new urxvt instance by running `$ urxvt &` and finally get what I want:

```
$ echo "а" | od -t x1
0000000 c1 0a
```

Why doesn't `LANG` change the behavior in the first place?

Comment: Posted an answer applicable for a `bash` shell, which login shell is `urxvt` using?

Comment: Which startup files are read by `urxvt`, add the line with changing locale there. It should reflect it for all your subsequent sessions.

Comment: Probably it uses bash. `add the line with changing locale there` - the problem is not about changing locale at all, but changing it in the CURRENT session. I know I can put this line at .bash_profile or .bashrc - but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 20):

There are two factors:

- you may be using a shell with a built-in echo (and have not informed the shell that you are changing the locale)
- **`LANG`** is not the first environment variable checked.  According to [`locale(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html), **`LC_ALL`** and **`LC_CTYPE`** would be checked first:

```
       If the second argument to setlocale(3) is an empty string, "", for
       the default locale, it is determined using the following steps:

       1.     If there is a non-null environment variable LC_ALL, the value
              of LC_ALL is used.

       2.     If an environment variable with the same name as one of the
              categories above exists and is non-null, its value is used for
              that category.

       3.     If there is a non-null environment variable LANG, the value of
              LANG is used.
```

For the latter, look at the output from the [`locale`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locale.1.html) command, which lists all of the environment variables which would be used:

```
$ export LANG=ru_RU.KOI8-R
$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.KOI8-R
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Just changing **`LANG`** should not change the other variables, but changing **`LC_ALL`** generally does that.

```
$ export LC_ALL=ru_RU.KOI8-R
$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.KOI8-R
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.KOI8-R"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.KOI8-R"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.KOI8-R"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.KOI8-R"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.KOI8-R"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.KOI8-R"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.KOI8-R"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.KOI8-R"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.KOI8-R"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.KOI8-R"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.KOI8-R"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.KOI8-R"
LC_ALL=ru_RU.KOI8-R
```

Comment: `(and have not informed the shell that you are changing the locale)` - if so, how to do it? `cat`'s output the same. BTW, I've tried your suggestions for `LC_ALL` - still doesn't work (if to be more explicit for encoding stdin).

Comment: Changing `LANG` didn't succeed in informing the shell, because it had other variables to check first.

Comment: Got it, but what the solution? Or there is no way?

Comment: My example changing **`LC_ALL`** shows the solution.

Comment: Anyways, you cannot change the terminal-emulator's behaviour via shell variables. There might be an escape-sequence for that like ESC %   G and ESC % @

Comment: That doesn't apply to urxvt: it only does UTF-8.